# How to layer shapes in flexbox

Tags: html, css, position, flexbox

I am currently using [this solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvqRep?editors=1100) for modified for my use [case specifically here](http://codepen.io/aisflat439/pen/NpvYXE). When I originally saw the design I figured that I would make two divs inside one flexbox container, the div on the right would be z index'd above the one on the right. Something like...

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 200px;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .left-side {
      flex: 4;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .right-side {
      flex: 1;
      background-color: orange;
      z-index: 3;
      border-style: 2px solid white;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="left-side">
        View Cart
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
```

This doesn't layer my elements on top of one another at all because they are positioned next to each other. *So my question is:*

How can I use make a layered layout while still taking advantage of all the nice positioning flexbox allows without the position absolute / position relative solution that I'm hacking together? Or, is this position absolute / relative the correct way to solve my problem?

Comment: is this what you try to do ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZxLNj

Comment: My proposition http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWvdNP

Comment: Yes that is very close to the end goal @GCyrillus, your solution is an improvement over mine as well.

Comment: i updated the pen and removed the absolute positionning ;) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZxLNj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the red background to the container, and use `transform: translateX(50%)` to move the orange circle half way outside of the container to pull off that effect.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  content: '';
}

.container:before,
.count {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.left-side {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.count {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side center">
    View Cart
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="count center">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I spent some with each solution. All the posted solutions are good. I selected this because​I think the transform makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Negative margins**

You can use negative margins to solve the problem without using position absolute/relative solution.

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 200px;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .left-side {
      flex: 4;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .right-side {
      flex: 1;
      background-color: orange;
      z-index: 3;
      border-style: 2px solid white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-left: -60px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="left-side">
        View Cart
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
```